# XPath query to select element by certain implementation

Tags: xml, xpath

what is the correct query to select the the "**Abstract**" Node which is implemented by **XYZImpl** from **http://www.namspace.org/impl**?

```
<...>
  <Abstract xmlns:q3="http://www.namspace.org/impl"
                xsi:type="q3:XYZImpl">
    <...></...>
  </Abstract>
  <Abstract xmlns:q8="http://www.namspace.org/another"
                xsi:type="q8:XYZImpl">
    <...></...>
  </Abstract>
 </...>
```

**order** and namespace **prefix** are **not** under my control

If the document just contains unique implementations the following query "works":

```
//Abstract[contains(@xsi:type,'XYZImpl')]
```

but I am searching for the right specification for the **full qualified Name** (namespace + Name)... :/

Comment: What XPATH library are you using? You can provide a namespace map to XPATH queries, but how exactly you do this depends on the implementation

Comment: MS XML.NET with c# 4.0 and the namespaces are mapped, so that it is possible to select nodes like this "//myownprefix:Node" but I have no idea to bypass the string compare for xsi:type=" **q8:** XYZImpl"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
   /*/Abstract
       [substring-after(@xsi:type, ':') = 'XYZImpl']
          [namespace::*
              [name() = substring-before(../@xsi:type, ':')
              and
               . = 'http://www.namspace.org/impl'
              ]
          ]
```

This selects any `Abstract` child of the top element of the XML document that has a namespace with a prefix, which is also the prefix of the QName value contained in its `xsi:type` attribute. *And* the "local-name" part of the QName value contained in the `xsi:type` attribute is exactly the string `"XYZImpl"` .

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xsi="some:xsi">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "/*/Abstract
           [substring-after(@xsi:type, ':') = 'XYZImpl']
              [namespace::*
                  [name() = substring-before(../@xsi:type, ':')
                  and
                   . = 'http://www.namspace.org/impl'
                  ]
              ]
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (produced by the provide, by making it well-formed):

```
<t xmlns:xsi="some:xsi">
      <Abstract xmlns:q3="http://www.namspace.org/impl"
                    xsi:type="q3:XYZImpl">
       </Abstract>
      <Abstract xmlns:q8="http://www.namspace.org/another"
                    xsi:type="q8:XYZImpl">
      </Abstract>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct element is selected and copied to the output**:

```
<Abstract xmlns:q3="http://www.namspace.org/impl" xmlns:xsi="some:xsi" xsi:type="q3:XYZImpl"/>
```

**Do note**: In order for the XPath expression to be evaluated successfully, the appropriate namespace with prefix `xsi` must be registered with your XPath implementation.

Comment: 1UP, see I knew that there was a better way. Is there a practical difference between chaining predicates and using `and`?

Comment: @MattH: Yes, there is a difference -- especially if a context-dependent expression like `position()` is used inside the predicates.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, answering xml questions is easier with valid samples....

It might not be the best way, but the following works for me:

```
//Abstract[namespace::*[.="http://www.namspace.org/impl"] and contains(@xsi:type,":XYZImpl")]
```